# How to target CSS :last-of-type of consecutive elements (not ALL within a parent element)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Maybe this is not possible in CSS3 but I'm trying to automatically insert comma separators when there is multiple consecutive instances of footnotes within a paragraph.

The problem occurs when there is another footnote later on in the paragraph. You'll notice in **Example 2** that the comma get's inserted after Footnote 2.

I've tried to switch it around and use first-child but this just ends in a reverse of the same problem.

```
sup:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: ",";}

sup:last-child::before {
    content: "";
}
```

Anyone know of a way to target the last-of-type when it's succeeded by any other content other than another of the same type?

```css
sup:after {
        content: ",";
    }

sup:last-of-type:after {
        content: "";
    }
```

```html
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<p>lorem upsum<sup>1,2</sup></p>

<h2>Example 2</h2>
<p>lorem upsum<sup>1,2</sup> flotsam jetsum<sup>3</sup></p>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused-- can you provide an example of what the desired outcome is?

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: How is your `<sup>` being generated? Do you write `<sup>1,2</sup>` manually?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer: all you need to do is remove ALL your *CSS* as it's practically doing nothing.

```
sup:after {
   content: ",";
}

sup:last-of-type:after {
        content: "";
    }
```

In your *html*, your code is `<sup>1,2</sup>` , which means you are already manually inputting the `,` for multiple values within `<sup>`.

That particular `,` within a `<sup>` with multiple values is not being generated by the above *CSS* but rather, is there only because you are manually typing it in.

In  a `<p>` with only a single `<sup>`, the reason why it does not have a `,` is because of your class `sup:last-of-type:after`. Since that there is only a single instance of `<sup>` it is considered the last one too, thus, it adds content of `""` to the end of it. Which once again is doing nothing since by default it's empty.

```html
<h2>Example 1</h2>
<p>lorem upsum<sup>1,2</sup></p>

<h2>Example 2</h2>
<p>lorem upsum<sup class="sup-multiple">1,2</sup> flotsam jetsum<sup>3</sup></p>
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to update your question as your `<sup>` content should be generated from somewhere. Else, run the snippet and you'll realise your *CSS* is not doing anything logically.